# Smooth diagonal line in css

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a diagonal line with the following code:

```
<div class="diagonal_line"></div>

.diagonal_line {
  border-bottom: 50px solid #212121;
  border-left: 8px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

But the line gets jagged. Is it possible to have a smoother diagonal line with only css?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f8cpX/

**UPDATE:**
- It appears jagged on FF (22.0) and Safari (5.1.9), but not on Chrome (28.0).
- I'm looking for diagonal shape (see the demo), not only the line.

Comment: I think that's OS-relevant, on my Mac it looks great but I know on a Windows machine they do smoothing not as good, especially for fonts and CSS borders

Comment: I definitely see anti-aliasing here on my Win7 in FF but it's not perfect. And yes, all this rendering of antialiased shapes (even fonts) look quite different in different browsers and OSes.

Comment: See update. Preferably cross-browser, only "modern" browsers of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Force hardware accelration:

```
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8cpX/7/)
and a nice [tutorial](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/21/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/)